# IIS File Download without Extension

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

I've got a .NET Web API 2 application, I've hooked up the api to send me a file id and from there I get the unique file from the server.

Example:

```
   <a href="api/attachment/232-2323-2323-2323">Download</a>
```

I need it to be a unique id since there could be multiples of the file in the repo.  However, when I try to click the download button I get a :

```
 HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
 The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

I was thinking a re-write rule might be a good action, but I dont really want to rewrite it, i just want to allow anything /api/attachment no matter what the rest.

I've already got one rewrite rule since my page is a single-page-application to direct responses to the Default.cshtml like:

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Default" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(?!Lib|api|Assets|Views|Directives|Services|Controllers|signalr).*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="Default.cshtml" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

any thoughts on best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve by creating an iframe and setting the src to the download like:

```
 $("body").append('<iframe name="downloadFrame" id="download_iFrame" style="display:none;" src="" />');
```

and then in the C# I set the header like:

```
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
```